# Android: how can I send verification email

Tags: java, php, android

I'm developing an android app, and after the user registers, i'd like to send him a verification email according to the mail he entered in the registration process.

I saw several answers here but they all have the same problem:

1. Only Gmail
2. Send mail to self , so you know the username and pwd.

How can I do it so I can send it to anyone no matter the mail provider?

I have a PHP backend, is it better to do it there?

Comment: The registration happens on the server side?

Comment: Are you capturing the input inside a webview simply hosting your registration page or some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go for the back-end, for several reasons:

1. If there is a central back-end which handles administration, it should be in charge of user administration and confirmation.
2. Sending email from the phone means more data usage to the user.
3. Sending email from the phone only works if the user is on a network that allows SMTP-connections outside its own subnet. Many ISPs, for example, do not allow that.

Answer (score 0):

The verification email should definitively be sent from your server.